# Sybase ASE 15.x ODBC driver on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, odbc, 64-bit, sap-ase

I have trouble getting the Sybase ASE ODBC drivers to work on Windows 7 64bit.

I have a 64bit version for Sybase ASE 15.0.1. However the installation fails. After selecting a "Custom" installation, and selecting all the options required for the client, the Java-based installer just disappears into thin air when clicking NEXT.

I have tried installing the 32 bit driver as well. This installed fine, but the driver does not show up in the ODBC Administrator.

Has anyone found a solution, or have a suggestion for this one? We are developing .NET tools against the Sybase backend, and can't get this to work at present.

Comment: We resolved this by installing the Sybase 15.0.3 64bit client

Answer (score 3):

> I have tried installing the 32 bit
>   driver as well. This installed fine,
>   but the driver does not show up in the
>   ODBC Administrator.

Have you tried using both different odbcad32?
One is located in %windir%\syswow64 the other in %windir%\system32.

We've had similar issues here with windows 7 64bit and odbc-drivers not showing up.
Using the odbcad32.exe located in %windir%\syswow64, the drivers showed up ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved by installing the 64bit client of Sybase 15.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

when installing choose custom installation, there you will see option for 64 bit driver. typical/full installation only installs 32 bit driver.